# Update Balance Query Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I need help with a Banking Database in which I have to update the Balance Field of one table with the sum of (loan) repayments from another. My code only updates one repayment instead of the sum.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Grammar; spacing.

Comment: Can you post the SQL code instead of the visual grid?